# Different directions of scrolling and scrollbar (jQuery Scrollbar Plugin)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll, scrollbar, custom-scrolling

is it possible to scroll a div vertically with a horizontal scrollbar? (see image - f.e. by sliding the circle to the right you would scroll down)

It would be great if this would be possible with a popular jquery scrollbar plugin so I can use some advanced options without coding too much...

Thank you very much.

-- CHECK IMAGE FOR UNDERSTANDING:

[image]